# Comparison between Layout Binding and Manual Binding(with observe) in MVVM architecture of android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-jetpack, android-mvvm

Using Android Jetpack components and MVVM architecture, we can get live data updates in a View from a View Model in 2 ways, one is to bind the layout with the live data variable, other way is to observe the variable in code.
To illustrate my question I have taken an example. Suppose there is a view model interface getTimeString() which returns the current time.

a) **Layout Data Binding**

1. The view in the layout looks something like this

   ```
       <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       ... 
       app:binder_data_date="@{sampleVM.timeString}"/>
   ```
2. The binding adapter looks something like this

   ```
   @BindingAdapter("binder_data_date")
   public static void binder_data_date(TextView text, String data) {
       text.setText(data);
   }
   ```

b) **Manual Data binding** (just to give it a name):
In Manual data binding, there is nothing in the layout view with respect to the binder, and I observe the live data using the observe() and update the textview.

```
 FragmentSplashScreenManualBindingBinding fragmentSplashScreenBinding;
SampleViewModel sampleViewModel1 = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SampleViewModel.class);

public void onSomeRandomFunc(...) {
 .... 
 sampleViewModel1.getTimeString().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), data -> {
        fragmentSplashScreenBinding.sampleText.setText(data);
    });
 }
```

I know the first method is much easier to use and both works.

1. But is using the second method and the way to access the variable (fragmentSplashScreenBinding.sampleText.setText()) in fragment to update the View correct?
2. Will the performance get impacted if I use the second method?

Answer (score 1):

Your manual Data binding is not incorrect and doesn't have a significant impact on the performance but you will lose two benefits:

1. **Null pointer exception handling:** `Layout Data Binding` handles null data and you don't need to check null objects to prevent app crash when you want to extract data objects and pass them to views.
2. **Code Reusability:** If you want to use your layout in different `Activities`, with
   `Layout Data Binding` you just need to pass the data variable to the layout. But for `Manual Data binding` you should copy the same code for each java class to assign variable to views which will make a lot of boilerplate code in complex views.

Moreover, If you are using data binding to replace `findViewById()` as your second method there is a better way called `View Binding` which you can read more about it [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding).

Comment: Are you sure that layout handles the null? I have seen null getting passed to the binder function as well if it is sent from the view model. Can you give some android documentation reference for the same ?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding @Saby

Comment: Also, you can test it yourself

Answer (score 1):

Instead of answering your 2 points in post directly - let me mention few key features of both data binding and Live data - which may eventually help you choose 1 over the other.

Live data class supports **Transformations** - this useful class provide a way to apply any changes to be done to the live data object before dispatching it to the observers, or you may need to return a different `LiveData` instance based on the value of another one. Below is a sample example of applying the Transformation on `LiveData` from Official android docs,

> class ScheduleViewModel : ViewModel() {
> val userName: LiveData
>
> ```
> init {
>     val result = Repository.userName
>     userName = Transformations.map(result) { result -> result.value }
> } }
> ```

As you can see from above example - in the "`init`" the `LiveData` Object is "transformed" using `Transformations.map` before dispatching its content to "observers"

Data binding is mostly works with set of Observables and cannot "transform" the data under observation before dispatching like in above example.

Another useful feature of with `LiveData` is a class called `MediatorLiveData` - this subclass which may observe other `LiveData` objects and react based on changes to it - With data binding AFAIK its very much restricted to a specific Observable Fields.